# Tts share android studio

Tags: android, share, text-to-speech

can someone help-me with this? I made an "tts app" that speak what de users enter in a textfield. But now i want to share this tts but i can't, I need made casting for the tts to an mp3 or some like this before sharing? An if yes, how can I do it? Thanks.

Here is the code to share:

```
private void shareAudio()
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
        intent.setType("audio/3gpp");
        startActivity( intent );
    }
```

PS: I seem one or two questions with the same problem but i really don't understand.

Comment: Where have you saved the audio output of the TTS to?